# "The system is running in low-graphics mode" when trying to upgrade to 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I have been using Ubuntu for a few years and have been very happy with it. I am not very knowledgeable about computers and software stuff. After I clicked on the upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.1, it downloaded the program and when I went to restart the computer to finish the process it restarted. I received a message stating

> The system is running in low graphics mode. Your screen, graphics card
>   and input device setting could not be detected correctly you will need
>   to correct this yourself.

How do I do this? Please give very simple instructions in non technical language. I have an Acer computer and Samsung monitor.

Comment: Are you able to tell us which model Acer computer you have?  It will often be on a sticker on the side or back of the computer case.  Also the same information for your Samsung monitor would help.